# Decoding a QR code with ZXing

Tags: image, decode, qr-code, zxing

I'm working on Js and I need to decode some QR codes of pictures stored on the PC, not uploaded in a server. I know how to decode codes through the ZXing URL, e.g.:

http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http://www.qrstuff.com/images/sample.png

So, I can make an XMLHttpRequest and solved! But the problem is I have the images on the computer and I want to avoid to upload them in a server.

I tryed to do something like this, but it didn't work:

http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=file:///home/gal/Desktop/QR_code_demo.jpg

And I also tryed to put an image64 string, but it didn't work either:

[http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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)](http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=url%28data%3aimage/jpeg;base64,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%29)

Any idea?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem; to my understanding, both approaches you tried out would 'upload the image in a server', which you write you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Codor if you click on the first link, you could see the decoder working. But it is working with an uploaded image. I need to do it with local image files. If you click the other two examples you will see it doesn't work

Comment: Obviously, you cannot send an image file to a server by sending a local file path as a GET parameter. Base64 encoding doesn't seem to be an option with zxing.com either, so it's not surprising that those two methods aren't working.

Answer (score 1):

The ZXing server must be able to read the image, but it can download it from your computer.

From their website you can upload an image (http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx). You could use the URL used by the formulary.

This must be a **multipart/form-data POST request to http://zxing.org/w/decode**.

The file is sent in the body of the request. Any Ajax File uploader should be good.

Comment: Ours-Polaire I really don't understand. Can you give me an example? I am limited to use just JS (I can't use Ajax) but what I understand about you said is something like this (not working): http://jsfiddle.net/JPXYG/29/

Comment: Does zxing.org's decode function support cross-domain requests?